# Change Bootstrap theme in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating MVC application by using bootstrap. However, I cannot change the bootstrap theme once the application is created.

When I create initial MVC with default bootstrap template, everything works fine. I check bootswatch.com or getbootstrap.com, there are many fantastic bootstrap theme. So I replaced the default "bootstrap.css" file by the one online.

The navbar looks strange, it collapsed, and all buttons, texts in a weird color.

I found there are bootstrap plugins in Visual Studio 2015, I can create the MVC by selecting different theme template, and its works fine. But if I change the bootstrap.css, the same problems happen.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: You're definitely using Bootstrap themes that are compatible with the version you're using in your MVC app? (E.g. Bootstrap 3 or 4)

Comment: Are you clearing your browser cache when viewing the new .css file?

Comment: I am using MVC version 5, I tried multiple bootstrap version including newest one(I just referenced the link online, so it should be the newest), they all have this kind of problem. The only bootstrap works would be the default one come with the MVC app